# Unable to deploy Flask App on Google App Engine getting an error "502 Bad Gateway"

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy a simple `Flask` application on the Google App Engine, Issue is that code is getting deployed without an error but when I access the URL of the deployed app then I get the error `"502 Bad Gateway"`

[image]

**Logs**

[image]

Below is the code I am using

[image]

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
 python_version: 3

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 1
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y apt-utils \
    python3.6 \
    python3-pip
    
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["main.py"]
```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return jsonify('Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask
gunicorn
```

Comment: The default port is 8080. Flask listens on port 5000. Change your code: `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)`

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks it worked, can you put that as an answer so that I can accept it as a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting @JohnHanley's comment for visibility.

The default port is 8080. Flask listens on port 5000. Change your code as follows: `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)`