# Port XXXX is in use by another program. Either identify and stop that program, or start the server with a different port

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to run a single python flask hello world. I deploy to App Engine, but it's showing like it's saying that the port is in use and it looks like it's running on multiple instances/threads/clones concurrently.

This is my main.py

```python
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello')
def helloIndex():
    print("Hello world log console")
    return 'Hello World from Python Flask!'

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=4444)
```

This is my app.yaml

```yaml
runtime: python38
env: standard
instance_class: B2
handlers:
  - url: /
    script: auto
  - url: .*
    script: auto
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

This is my requirements.txt

```plaintext
gunicorn==20.1.0
flask==2.2.2
```

And this is the logs that I got:

```plaintext
* Serving Flask app 'main'
* Debug mode: off
Address already in use
Port 4444 is in use by another program. Either identify and stop that program, or start the server with a different port.
[2022-08-10 15:57:28 +0000] [1058] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1058)
[2022-08-10 15:57:29 +0000] [1059] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1059
[2022-08-10 15:57:29 +0000] [1060] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1060
[2022-08-10 15:57:29 +0000] [1061] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1061
```

It says that Port 4444 is in use. Initially I tried 5000 (flask's default port) but it says it's in use. Also I tried removing the `port=4444` but now it's saying `Port 5000 is in use by another program`, I guess flask by default assign port=5000. I'm suspecting that it's because GAE is running in multiple instances that's causing this error. If not, then please help to solve this issue.

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73196295/15211203

Comment: Does this answer your question? [App Engine Flask App: Process terminated because the request deadline was exceeded. (Error code 123)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73124893/app-engine-flask-app-process-terminated-because-the-request-deadline-was-exceed)

Comment: Now it says `Port 8080 is in use by another program. Either identify and stop that program, or start the server with a different port.`.... Pls help...

Answer (score 17):

I solved using `lsof` and `kill` commands. In my case, error message mentioned port 5000 so I first checked which processes(s) are using port 5000 by calling `lsof -i:5000` in the terminal. Once I located the `PID` of already running `Flask` application, I killed it using this command: `kill -9 <PID>` and voilà!

This approach should work for both mac and Linux users. If Windows users can find the equivalent of the `lsof` and `kill` Linux commands, it may work there as well.

Comment: How do you do it with GCP?

Answer (score 3):

## Type command in terminal

```
lsof -i :5000
```

## Use the below command to kill PID(s)

```
kill -9 PID
```

### Note: PID is always numeric. Ex:- kill -9 2882

Comment: how do you do it with GCP

Answer (score 1):

App Engine apps should listen on port 8080 and not in any other ones.

So you may need to set this like

```py
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Comment: Now it says `Port 8080 is in use by another program. Either identify and stop that program, or start the server with a different port.`.... Pls help...

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac, this could also be caused by your AirPlay Receiver running on port 5000 (if you try the kill commands others have suggested, it just starts another process.)

Unchecking "AirPlay Receiver" in your sharing settings will handle this for you! (See apple forum thread [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332))

Answer (score 0):

Close the editor and then reopen. When you stop the process next time use Ctrl+C if you're on the terminal

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. Delete your old file from your terminal and or folder that created the web app. In the terminal this is done by:

```
rm -file_name
```

Then try all over again with your a fresh file and it should be okay.

Comment: This doesn't in any way address the issue. The port is already being used, the best thing to do is to check for the PID of the service using the port, then kill it.